# Angular: Validation executed after the ngModelChange

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input with a customValidator named `fooValidator` (what it does is irrelevant here, it's just a custom validator which validate the input if it correponds to some regexp) :

```
               <form #contratForm="ngForm">
                    <input type="text"
                           class="validate"
                           [(ngModel)]="foo"
                           name="foo"
                           ngControl="foo"
                           fooValidator
                           (ngModelChange)="blah($event)"
                           required
                    />
                </form>
```

and in my component :

```
blah(event) {
  if(this.contratForm.controls.foo.valid){
     console.log("Valid")
  }
}
```

"Valid" is never shown in my console. It happens as the ngModelChange is executed before the validation. I can wrap my `blah` function in a `setTimeout` and "Valid" would appear. Is there any way to do so without the use of an hacky `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Is the validator async?

Comment: Not at all, it just check if the input is matched by a regexp. Is it supposed to be to work without the setTimeout ?

Comment: You could subscribe to `statusChanges` like shown in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#observe-control for `valueChanges`

Comment: It seems to do the trick ! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
this.contratForm.get('foo')
    .statusChanges.forEach(
       (s) => {
           console.log(s);
       }
    );
```